# how do I read from one s3 bucket using assume role and write to a different bucket (using my original session)?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have an AWS IAM role with permissions to read from a bucket of a different account.
I'm assuming the role and reading from the bucket successfully.
I'm currently downloading the objects and then writing them to my bucket.
I would love to use a copy command to copy the objects directly to my bucket without the unnecessary download.
I don't want to add a bucket policy to my bucket that would allow the role to write to it because I don't want the account that created the role to be able to write to it.

A short Diagram:

> Account 1:
>
> Bucket A
>
> Role @
>
> Account 2:
>
> Bucket B
>
> Currently:
>
> Read From Bucket A (Using role @) > To Server
>
> Write From Server (Using Account 2) > To Bucket B
>
> Desirable:
>
> Clone From Bucket A > To Bucket B

Can I use boto3 with multiple sessions? Can I create a role (which will be unavailable to the different account I don't control) that will allow me to use the permissions of the original role?

Comment: If you can't provide a single set of credentials that have access to both the source for GetObject and the destination for PutObject, then I think you'll have to use two boto3 sessions and either download then upload or potentially stream the content from source to destination.

Comment: @jarmod That's exactly what I'm currently doing, and I'm trying to see if there's a better way.

Comment: The [underlying API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_CopyObject.html) has no option to specify a different source session, so boto3 will have no such option.